# Get variable from user form to a module - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a user form that gets User (`User`) and Password (`PW`) in order to connect to a database, after user input these 2 information. (These 2 variables are collected from same user form)

Userform:

```
Option Explicit

Public PW As String
Public User As String
Public strConnectionString As String

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim objConn As ADODB.Connection    
strConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=XXXXXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXXXXX;User ID=" & User & ";Password=" & PW

Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection
objConn.Open strConnectionString
   
Unload Me

End Sub
```

This part works fine (User form), however, after that, I have other modules that user can do queries using the connection already set `strConnectionString`, but even declaring this variable as `Public`, it is not pushing to the module

Module (just the beggining):

```
Option Explicit

Public strConnectionString As String

Public Sub Master_GetData_from_SQLServer()

Dim strQuery As String, strMessage As String
Dim objConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rsData As ADODB.Recordset

Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection
objConn.Open strConnectionString
```

I getting an error on `objConn.Open strConnectionString` ("Run-Time Error '-2147467259 (80004005): [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified)

I have tried to see if the variable was been pushed from user form by input (`strConnectionString`) on a cell and nothing is brought there

```
Worksheets("Query").Range("L3").Value = strConnectionString
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't you at least need a quote before this part? `Source=XXXXXXX`

Comment: I just forgot to input it on the question (i have fixed here) thanks to point it out, but my code already have it, the issue is related to the public variable

Comment: OK looks like you added the provider too - which is required. Please verify your ODBC driver/configuration and your Office version are both either 64 bit or 32 bit - they have to match.

Comment: I have checked, if I input manually the `User` and `PW` directly on the code, it works, but I want to take these 2 variables from the user form

Comment: Try removing your declaration of `strConnectionString` in your userform. If you've got it declared as public in your module, that should be fine/enough. The module is in the same workbook, right? Because I didn't test yet with the module in Personal/addin. Also, if the `CommandButton1_Click()` is in the Userform code, where are you filling your variables PW/User? (it's always best to declare your variables a little different in case there's an issue with excel/vba pre-existing variables)

Comment: When you run `Unload Me` the user form object is destroyed,  including its public variables.

Comment: It has worked, you are right, module it is on same workbook

Comment: @Notus_Panda, thank you for your help

Comment: You may want to understand what is 
 [Name Shadowing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esmB4sAe0z0&t=671s). (*A variable in a lower scope is given the same name as a variable in a higher scope.*)

Answer (score 1):

It is the scope issue of objConn object. objConn is available only in your Sub CommandButton1_Click().  If you want to reuse objConn after get connected, make it Public or reconnect it from the module. :)